# How to call a stored procedure that inserts data to multiple tables in hibernate

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

Hi I am trying to execute a stored procedure that inserts value to multiple tables using hibernate. I am new to using stored procedures with hibernate.

While browsing I came across 3 methods. However I am not sure of how to implement it since the procedure affects 2 different tables.

Please help.

Below is my stored procedure (SQL 2008)

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[WRITE_DETAILS_SP]

 @crNo varchar(30), 
 @existing [decimal](30, 10),
 @sought [decimal](30, 10),
 @no varchar(10),
 @type varchar(100),
 @createdUser varchar(50), 
 @createdDate datetime,
 @modifiedUser varchar(50),
 @modifiedDate datetime

 AS

 BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[DETAILS]
       ([CR_NO]
       ,[EXISTING]
       ,[SOUGHT]
       ,[NO]
       ,[TYPE]
       ,[CREATED_USER]
       ,[CREATED_DATE]
       ,[MODIFIED_USER]
       ,[MODIFIED_DATE])

 VALUES
       (@crNo,
        @existing,
        @dought,
        @no,
        @type,
        @createdUser,
        @createdDate,
        @modifiedUser,
        @modifiedDate);


 INSERT INTO [dbo].[CALCULATIONS]
       ([CR_NO]
       ,[TYPE]
       ,[LIMIT]
       ,[CREATED_USER]
       ,[CREATED_DATE]
       ,[MODIFIED_USER]
       ,[MODIFIED_DATE])

 VALUES
       (@crNo,
        @type,
        @sought,
        @createdUser,
        @createdDate,
        @modifiedUser,
        @modifiedDate);

 END

 GO
```

Please help me on how to implement this using hibernate.

Currently I am using criteria based methods for all CRUD  operations each of which is related to a particular class.

Below is my AbstractDAO class which is inherited by all the dao implementations

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<PK extends Serializable, T> {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private final Class<T> persistentClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractDAO() {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}


protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public T getByKey(PK key) {
    return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
}

public void persist(T entity) {
    getSession().persist(entity);
}

public void save(T entity) {
    getSession().save(entity);
}

public void update(T entity) {
    getSession().update(entity);
}

public void delete(T entity) {
    getSession().delete(entity);
}

public void flush(){
    getSession().flush();
}

public void refresh(T entity){
    getSession().refresh(entity);
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria() {
    return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
}
```

Please help on how to implement the stored procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _While browsing I came across 3 methods_ Have you tried any of these methods and something is not working?

Comment: @jusermar10 these methods are specific to the insert or select to/from single table but in my case multiple tables are involved and hence I cant relate it to a single model class.

Comment: @eccentricCoder how did you solve this?